# Update with multiple values in WHERE

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, where-clause, multiple-columns

I need to update the field in database when it match the two conditions 
below is my code
 this is the query which is working fine for one value in `WHERE` condition

```
query2 = "UPDATE  Game_mygame 
          SET game_played = "+str(set_game_played)+" 
          WHERE home_teamID = "+str(i.home_teamID)
```

but I need to match two values in `WHERE` and I am trying the following

```
query2 = "UPDATE  Game_mygame 
              SET game_played = "+str(set_game_played)+" 
              WHERE home_teamID = "+str(i.home_teamID)+ 
                    "AND away_teamID = "+str(i.away_teamID)
```

but this one gives the syntax error

Please suggest me where I am doing mistake

Comment: And what error are you getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is no space between first `WHERE` condition and `AND`. So it will make your query like this `WHERE home_teamID=xyzAND` instead of `WHERE home_teamID=xyz AND`. So you need to give an extra space before `AND` (same as you have given it before `WHERE`)

```
query2 = "UPDATE  Game_mygame 
              SET game_played = "+str(set_game_played)+
              " WHERE home_teamID = "+str(i.home_teamID)+ 
              "AND away_teamID = "+str(i.away_teamID)
           ---^^--- Space is missing here
```

So try this:

```
query2 = "UPDATE  Game_mygame 
              SET game_played = "+str(set_game_played)+
              " WHERE home_teamID = "+str(i.home_teamID)+ 
              " AND away_teamID = "+str(i.away_teamID)
```

Answer (score 1):

Concat with `.` like

```
query2 = "UPDATE  Game_mygame 
          SET game_played = ".str(set_game_played)." 
          WHERE home_teamID = '". str(i.home_teamID) ."'
          AND away_teamID = '".str(i.away_teamID)."'";
```

And also as **@Preet Sangha** said we can use ids without quotes like

```
query2 = "UPDATE  Game_mygame 
          SET game_played = ".str(set_game_played)." 
          WHERE home_teamID = ". str(i.home_teamID) ."
          AND away_teamID = ".str(i.away_teamID);
```

Comment: are single quotes needed around the literals? like game_played = ' ".str(set_game_played)."'

Comment: I just suggested for the concat...We can use quotes also.